# converting json results to a proper date - javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Hi i am trying to convert a json date back to a normal dd/mm/yy date.

How can i convert the Customer.DateOfBirth dd/mm/yy from a json date back to a normal date?

Here my code?

```
  // parse the date
                var Birth = Customer.DateOfBirth;
                if (Birth != '') {
                    // get the javascript date object
                    Birth = DateFromString(Birth, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                    if (Birth == 'Invalid Date') {
                        Birth = null
                    }
                    else {
                        // get a json date
                        Birth = DateToString(Birth);
                        //REPLACE JSON DATE HERE WITH NORMAL DATE??
                    }
                }
```

Any suggestion would be great.
Thanks

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: what format is the `Birth` variable and what do the `DateFromString` and `DateFromString` functions do?

Comment: customer.DateOfBirth is dd/mm/yy.. my questions is its saving as a json date at the moment i need to convert that. i dont know how i would go about doing it..

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the JSON representation to `yyyy/mm/dd` then you can directly convert it using

```
Birth = new Date(Birth);
```

If you have to use the current format, then you have to do some manual parsing

Extract the day/month/year parts and create a string in the expected format

```
var parts = Birth.split('/'),
    day = parts[0],
    month = parts[1],
    year = parts[2],// you need to find a way to add the "19" or "20" at the beginning of this since the year must be full for the parser.
    fixedDate = year + '/' + month + '/' + day; 

Birth = new Date(fixedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Date` object from `mm/dd/yyyy` string, so if your string is ordered `dd/mm/yyyy` you'll either get `Invalid Date` error, or, possibly worse, create a Date object with wrong date (Januray 10th instead of October 1st).

So you need to swap the `dd` and `mm` parts of your string before passing it to the `Date` constructor:

```
var datestr = Customer.DateOfBirth.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/,"$2/$1/$3");
Birth = new Date( datestr );
```

You could also pass a string in `yyyy/mm/dd` order:

```
var datestr = Customer.DateOfBirth.split('/').reverse().join('/');
Birth = new Date( datestr );
```